# android append images to a array list, app gets stopped unfortunately

Tags: android, image, arraylist, out-of-memory

I'm new to the android development and I'm trying to create a gallery application and it's almost done.

In my code there's a for loop which is getting images. It's working properly about less than 60 images. But greater than 60, when I run the application it 'stopped unfortunately'.

There is a issue with the cache memory I guess.
I checked the 'Caching Bitmaps' tutorial on Android Developers site as well. (http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/cache-bitmap.html)
But I couldn't find a way to resolve my problem.
Can someone please help me?

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.men);

    gridView = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.gridView);
    customGridAdapter = new GridViewAdapter(this, R.layout.row_grid, getData());
    gridView.setAdapter(customGridAdapter);

    ...

    });
}

private ArrayList getData() {
    final ArrayList imageItems = new ArrayList();
    TypedArray imgs = getResources().obtainTypedArray(R.array.image_men);
    for (int i = 0; i < 80; i++) {
        Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(this.getResources(),
                imgs.getResourceId(i, -1));
        imageItems.add(new ImageItem(bitmap, "Image#" + i));
    }

    return imageItems;

}
```

**class ImageItem**

```
private Bitmap image;
private String title;

public ImageItem(Bitmap image, String title) {
    super();
    this.image = image;
    this.title = title;
}

public Bitmap getImage() {
    return image;
}
```

public **class GridViewAdapter** extends ArrayAdapter

```
private Context context;
private int layoutResourceId;
private ArrayList data = new ArrayList();

public GridViewAdapter(Context context, int layoutResourceId, ArrayList data) {
    super(context, layoutResourceId, data);
    this.layoutResourceId = layoutResourceId;
    this.context = context;
    this.data = data;
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    View row = convertView;
    ViewHolder holder = null;

    if (row == null) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = ((Activity) context).getLayoutInflater();
        row = inflater.inflate(layoutResourceId, parent, false);
        holder = new ViewHolder();
        holder.image = (ImageView) row.findViewById(R.id.image);
        row.setTag(holder);
    } else {
        holder = (ViewHolder) row.getTag();
    }

    ImageItem item = (ImageItem) data.get(position);
    holder.image.setImageBitmap(item.getImage());
    return row;
}

static class ViewHolder {
    ImageView image;
}
```

**Error Log**

```
01-16 09:43:56.281: E/dalvikvm-heap(24293): Out of memory on a 1310416-byte allocation.
01-16 09:43:56.298: E/AndroidRuntime(24293): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
01-16 09:43:56.298: E/AndroidRuntime(24293): java.lang.OutOfMemoryError
01-16 09:43:56.298: E/AndroidRuntime(24293):    at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.nativeDecodeAsset(Native Method)
01-16 09:43:56.298: E/AndroidRuntime(24293):    at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeStream(BitmapFactory.java:521)
01-16 09:43:56.298: E/AndroidRuntime(24293):    at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeResourceStream(BitmapFactory.java:374)
01-16 09:43:56.298: E/AndroidRuntime(24293):    at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeResource(BitmapFactory.java:397)
01-16 09:43:56.298: E/AndroidRuntime(24293):    at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeResource(BitmapFactory.java:427)
01-16 09:43:56.298: E/AndroidRuntime(24293):    at com.example.dayanath.posing.Men.getData(Men.java:52)
01-16 09:43:56.298: E/AndroidRuntime(24293):    at com.example.dayanath.posing.Men.onCreate(Men.java:29)
01-16 09:43:56.298: E/AndroidRuntime(24293):    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5122)
01-16 09:43:56.298: E/AndroidRuntime(24293):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1081)
01-16 09:43:56.298: E/AndroidRuntime(24293):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2307)
01-16 09:43:56.298: E/AndroidRuntime(24293):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2395)
01-16 09:43:56.298: E/AndroidRuntime(24293):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:162)
01-16 09:43:56.298: E/AndroidRuntime(24293):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1364)
01-16 09:43:56.298: E/AndroidRuntime(24293):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:107)
01-16 09:43:56.298: E/AndroidRuntime(24293):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:194)
01-16 09:43:56.298: E/AndroidRuntime(24293):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5371)
01-16 09:43:56.298: E/AndroidRuntime(24293):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
01-16 09:43:56.298: E/AndroidRuntime(24293):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
01-16 09:43:56.298: E/AndroidRuntime(24293):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:833)
01-16 09:43:56.298: E/AndroidRuntime(24293):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:600)
01-16 09:43:56.298: E/AndroidRuntime(24293):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
01-16 09:43:56.333: E/AppErrorDialog(534): Failed to get ILowStorageHandle instance
```

Comment: Please add the log for the exceptions.

Comment: please post your logcat

Comment: @yshahak I have added the logcat.

Comment: @CodeProcessor I have added the logcat

Comment: Is imgs.size equal to 80?

Comment: @user3290180 if imgs.size greater than about 65, application 'stopped unfortunately'

Comment: maybe there is a limit of memory usage when you call obtainTypedArray

Answer (score 0):

You exceeded the available memory - you only have a limited amount of memory and cannot store more there than you have. You could use a LRU cache here and just store some in memory and others on flash

Comment: you are right, but he said that he used cache tutorial

Comment: Could anyone please tell me what are the necessary changes that I have to do to resolve my problem. Any coding guidance or any tutorials that I can understand the situation easily..

Comment: @user3290180 Yes! I have gone through that. But it's kind of a long tutorial that hard to understand.. :(

Comment: that topic is kind of complex - think the long complex tutorial you referenced is kind of what you are asking for ;-)